# change latitude and longitude dynamically on button click

Tags: google-maps

I want to change location of my google map center position on button click.

I have 3 buttons. USA, UK and China.

By default, when page loads it shows USA. I want that when I click on UK, it should center the
map to UK without refreshing the page. Same for china button.

How can we do this for google maps?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html) (uses a drop down list rather than buttons, but the concept is valid).

Comment: Thanks...I was looking for same concept...